# c# list intersect not working as expected

Tags: c#

I'm using this method to create some arrays and store them in the list blocks:

```
private void CreateBlocks()
    {
        if (size == 1)
        {
            blocks.Add(pos);
        }
        else if (orientation == "vert")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                blocks.Add(new int[]{pos[0] + i, pos[1]});
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                blocks.Add(new int[] { pos[0], pos[1] + i });
            }
        }
    }
```

and I'm trying to use this code to store the arrays of blocks list in the `shipsPos` list if none of the arrays already exist in `shipsPos`:

```
private void AddShips(int numberOfShips)
    {
        while (numberOfShips > 0)
        {
            Ship ship = new Ship();
            if (!shipsPos.Intersect(ship.Blocks).Any())
            {
                ships.Add(ship);
                shipsPos.AddRange(ship.Blocks);
                shipTypes[ship.Size] += 1;
                numberOfShips--;
            }
        }
    }
```

`Ship` is the class that the `CreateBlocks` method belongs. My problem is that even if an array already exists in `shipsPos` it gets added to the list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is `size`? Or `blocks`? What is `orientation`? Please give us some working code.

Comment: Arrays get compared by reference so that two arrays with identical elements do not equate to being equal. Hence `.Intersect(...)` treats them as separate arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays get compared by reference so that two arrays with identical elements do not equate to being equal. Hence `.Intersect(...)` treats them as separate arrays.

Try this code:

```
var xs = new [] { new [] { 1, 2 }, new [] { 3, 4 } };
var ys = new [] { new [] { 1, 2 }, new [] { 5, 6 } };

var zs = xs.Intersect(ys); // 0 elements!
```

This shows that arrays as elements do not get selected by `.Intersect(...)`.

To make `.Intersect(...)` work with nested arrays you need to implement your own `IEqualityComparer<T[]>`. Here's a simple one:

```
public class ArrayComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]>
{
    public bool Equals(T[] ts0, T[] ts1)
    {
        return ts0.SequenceEqual(ts1);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T[] ts)
    {
        return ts.Aggregate(0, (a, t) => (a >> 2) + t.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var zs = xs.Intersect(ys, new ArrayComparer<int>()); // 1 element!
```